Exporting GeoTIFF files in GEE over time series
I want to get rasters of individual ChlI and VDVI for the available dates over time
series from 30 points (puntos) in aoi.
This is my GEE code:
// Set parameters
var START_DATE = '2023-08-01';
var END_DATE = '2023-09-01';
var CLOUD_FILTER = 10;  // Maximum cloud cover percentage allowed in the image collection
var CLD_PRB_THRESH = 50; // Cloud probability threshold
var NIR_DRK_THRESH = 0.15; // Near-infrared reflectance threshold for cloud shadow
var CLD_PRJ_DIST = 1; // Maximum distance (km) to search for cloud shadows
var BUFFER = 50; // Buffer size in meters for puntos

// Function to filter and join Sentinel-2 SR and cloud probability collections
function get_s2_sr_cld_col(AOI, START_DATE, END_DATE) {
  var s2_sr_col = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
    .filterBounds(AOI)
    .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', CLOUD_FILTER));

  var s2_cloudless_col = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')
    .filterBounds(AOI)
    .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE);

  return ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveFirst('s2cloudless').apply({
    primary: s2_sr_col,
    secondary: s2_cloudless_col,
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: 'system:index',
      rightField: 'system:index'
    })
  }));
}

// Build cloudless image collection
var s2_sr_cld_col_eval = get_s2_sr_cld_col(AOI, START_DATE, END_DATE);

// Function to add cloud bands
function add_cloud_bands(img) {
  var cld_prb = ee.Image(img.get('s2cloudless')).select('probability');
  var is_cloud = cld_prb.gt(CLD_PRB_THRESH).rename('clouds');
  return img.addBands(ee.Image([cld_prb, is_cloud]));
}

// Function to add shadow bands
function add_shadow_bands(img) {
  var not_water = img.select('SCL').neq(6);
  var dark_pixels = img.select('B8').lt(NIR_DRK_THRESH * 1e4).multiply(not_water).rename('dark_pixels');
  var shadow_azimuth = ee.Number(90).subtract(ee.Number(img.get('MEAN_SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE')));
  var cld_proj = img.select('clouds').directionalDistanceTransform(shadow_azimuth, CLD_PRJ_DIST * 10)
    .reproject({crs: img.select(0).projection(), scale: 100})
    .select('distance').mask().rename('cloud_transform');
  var shadows = cld_proj.multiply(dark_pixels).rename('shadows');
  return img.addBands(ee.Image([dark_pixels, cld_proj, shadows]));
}

// Final cloud-shadow mask function
function add_cld_shdw_mask(img) {
  var img_cloud = add_cloud_bands(img);
  var img_cloud_shadow = add_shadow_bands(img_cloud);
  var is_cld_shdw = img_cloud_shadow.select('clouds').add(img_cloud_shadow.select('shadows')).gt(0)
    .focalMin(2).focalMax(BUFFER * 2 / 20)
    .reproject({crs: img.select(0).projection(), scale: 20})
    .rename('cloudmask');
  return img_cloud_shadow.addBands(is_cld_shdw);
}

// Apply the cloud-shadow mask
var masked = s2_sr_cld_col_eval.map(add_cld_shdw_mask);

// Function to calculate and add spectral indices
function addSpectralIndices(image) {
  var s2Bands = {
    'BLUE': image.select('B2').divide(10000),
    'GREEN': image.select('B3').divide(10000),
    'RED': image.select('B4').divide(10000),
    'NIR': image.select('B8').divide(10000),
    'SWIR1': image.select('B11').divide(10000),
    'RE1': image.select('B5').divide(10000)
  };

  var vdvi = image.expression('((2 * GREEN) - RED - BLUE) / ((2 * GREEN) + RED + BLUE)', s2Bands).rename('VDVI');
  var chli = image.expression('((NIR / RE1) - 1)', s2Bands).rename('ChlI');

  return image.addBands(ee.Image([vdvi, chli]));
}

// Add spectral indices to the collection
var TS_indices = masked.map(addSpectralIndices);
print("TS_indices with spectral indices", TS_indices);

// Create buffered points for each point in 'puntos'
var puntosbuff = puntos.map(function(pt) {
  return pt.buffer(BUFFER).bounds();
});
print("Buffered Points", puntosbuff);

// Define the indices to export
var exportBands = ['ChlI', 'VDVI']; // Specify the indices to export

// Filter images with both VDVI and ChlI bands
var filteredCollection = TS_indices.filter(ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.listContains('system:band_names', 'VDVI'),
  ee.Filter.listContains('system:band_names', 'ChlI')
));

// Print debug information for filtered collection
print("Filtered collection with VDVI and ChlI bands:", filteredCollection);

// Iterate over the filtered collection to export each image
filteredCollection.toList(filteredCollection.size()).evaluate(function(imageList) {
  if (Array.isArray(imageList)) {
    imageList.forEach(function(imageInfo) {
      var img = ee.Image(imageInfo.id); // Convert the image info into ee.Image

      // Get the acquisition date for naming
      var date = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyyMMdd').getInfo();

      // Export each specified band (VDVI and ChlI)
      exportBands.forEach(function(band) {
        Export.image.toDrive({
          image: img.select(band).clip(AOI), // Select and clip the specific index
          description: band + '_' + date, // Unique description for export
          folder: 'Sentinel2_Exports', // Folder in Google Drive
          fileNamePrefix: band + '_' + date, // Unique file name
          region: AOI, // AOI for export
          scale: 10, // Scale in meters
          maxPixels: 1e9 // Handle large images
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    print('Error: imageList is not an array');
  }
});

I got this outcome in the submitted task:
VDVI_20230809
ID: TDSEU722ME3RZYRUR55WDC3J
Phase: Failed
Runtime: 0s (started 2024-12-14 17:58:54 +1030)
Attempted 1 time
Priority: 100 (default)
Error: Image.select: Band pattern 'VDVI' did not match any bands. Available bands: [B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B8A, B9, B11, B12, AOT, WVP, SCL, TCI_R, TCI_G, TCI_B, MSK_CLDPRB, MSK_SNWPRB, QA10, QA20, QA60, MSK_CLASSI_OPAQUE, MSK_CLASSI_CIRRUS, MSK_CLASSI_SNOW_ICE] (Error code: 3)

How should I modify the code to get the rasters?

You are turning your image collection into a client-side list and then try to turn them back to server-side ee.Image objects. I don't know how to do that correctly, or if it's even possible. An alternative that doesn't require you to figure this out, and probably is more efficient, is to only turn the system:index of the images into a client-side array. You can then use client-side iteration to extract the corresponding ee.Image for each index and export it.
filteredCollection.aggregate_array('system:index').evaluate(function (indexes) {
  indexes.forEach(function (index) {
    var img = filteredCollection
      .filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', index))
      .first()
    ...
  })
})

https://code.earthengine.google.com/eca91817aa82907fa7b741d143667afc
